# How to change the attributes of a field in a form based on a value of certain dropdown option in jsp?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, if-statement, tags

i have scenerio where based on a padrticular value of some drop down , a specific set of attributes take action as in below example.i am using jsp and javascript

```
 <td width="20%"><select type="text" name="cars" style='WIDTH:428'            
       <option value="" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select></td></tr>
```

**based on the above selected option i want to choose like this**

```
 if (mercedes)
      <td ><input type="text" name="mercedes"  
         onchange="javascript:onefunction();"></td>
        else
       <td ><input type="text" name="othercars"    
       onchange="javascript: otherfunction();"></td>
```

please help?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this solution. Correct if im wrong.

### jsp html

```
 <%
 <tr>
 <td width="20%">
      <select type="text" name="cars" onChange="testing();">            
            <option value="" selected>Select</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 %>
```

### Javascript

```
<script language="Javascript">
function testing()
{
  var cars = document.mainform.cars.value;

  if(cars == 'volvo')
    functionA();
  else if(cars =='saab')
    functionB();
  else if(cars =='mercedes')
    functionC();
  else if(cars == 'audi')
    functionD();
  else 
    functionF();
}
function functionA()
{
     //your code
}
    function functionA()
{
     //your code
}
    function functionB()
{
     //your code
}
    function functionC()
{
     //your code
}
    function functionD()
{
     //your code
}
    function functionE()
{
     //your code
}
    function functionF()
{
     //your code
}
</script>
```